# Reading data from Arduino to Python using bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino

I'm sending data with Arduino through Bluetooth (jy-mcu HC-06), using this simple code:

```
int a;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  a = 0;
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(a);
  a++;
  delay(40);
}
```

My issue is that when I try to read the data with Python (on Linux), the first 20 seconds (approx.), some data is corrupted. But after this, I can read the data correctly without any other error.
Python code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/rfcomm0"
ser.baudrate = 57600
ser.open()

while True:
  print(ser.readline())
```

Arduino code is a loop that sends an integer every 40ms and sums one to this integer. An example of the data corrupted:

```
108
109
11161831191
192
193
194
195
1111
122222222222
2220
22266
267
268
269
270
133333533333633333373
33333333344444444444444444444444444444544444444444444444491
492
493
494
```

I power the Arduino with an external power supply that gives 5V and 3A with a lot of stability.

I tried to read the data with an Android Bluetooth terminal app and it worked perfectly all the time. For that reason, I suppose that the error is in the Python code.

I have read a lot of information on the Internet and I have made a lot of changes in the code but nothing solves the problem. This is one of my latest codes, just to show some of my tests:

```
import serial, time
import sys

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/rfcomm0"
ser.baudrate = 57600
ser.timeout = 1
ser.setDTR(False)
ser.setRTS(False)
ser.open()
old_data = 0
new_data = 0
ser.flushInput()
ser.flush()
ser.flushOutput()
time.sleep(1)

print("Start")
while True:
  raw_data = ser.readline()
  try:
    ser.flushInput()
    new_data = int(raw_data)
    ser.flush()
  except ValueError:
    pass
  print raw_data
  if (old_data != new_data -1 and old_data != 0):
print('ERROR#####################################################')
  old_data = new_data

  time.sleep(0.01)
```

I appreciate any help, and of course, I will post here any update on this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The baudrate of bluetooth module(HC-06) is different from that of Arduino.

Try `ser.baudrate = 115200` in your python code.